# Router login using Links2 webrowser for terminal

Tags: command-line, login, text, router

I can call up the router login page using the Links2 text based webrowser for terminal, and enter details but when I submit the form nothing happens... The router is TL-WR40N, the server is version 18.05.5 also the router is connected to the motherboard via LAN?

Comment: Not every router is going to be supported by Links2.  I know that mine is not mainly because Links2 does not support JavaScript.  See:  https://www.cnx-software.com/2014/02/09/building-elinks-text-based-web-browser-with-some-sort-of-javascript-support/

Comment: It seems that the available text browsers do not support JavaScript, thank you for the answer, kind regards and stay safe too.